# Use of unassigned local variable when using async/await

Tags: c#, async-await

This code, without `await`, compiles:

```
IEnumerable<PingResponse> pingResponses;
using (var prestoWcf = new PrestoWcf<IPingService>())
{
    pingResponses = prestoWcf.Service.GetAllForPingRequest(this.PingRequest);
}

foreach (PingResponse response in pingResponses) { // code here }
```

This code, with `await`, does not compile:

```
IEnumerable<PingResponse> pingResponses;
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (var prestoWcf = new PrestoWcf<IPingService>())
    {
        pingResponses = prestoWcf.Service.GetAllForPingRequest(this.PingRequest);
    }
});

foreach (PingResponse response in pingResponses) { // code here }
```

The error is: `Use of unassigned local variable 'pingResponses'`

Why would introducing async/await cause this issue?

Comment: You should send an asynchronous network request, rather than sending a synchronous request on a background thread.

Comment: So that you don't waste a thread.

Comment: Do you have a `GetAllForPingRequestsAsync`? Seeing that the class has WCF in it's name the WCF Proxy generation tools should be able to auto-generate a proxy that returns a `Task` (This is how you would implment SLaks's suggestion)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I do not have `GetAllForPingRequestsAsync` yet. Looks like I need to do this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @BobHorn if you are using `svcutil.exe` to generate your proxy classes ***do not*** add the `/async`, `/a`, or `/syncOnly` switches as that will override the default which does make the task based async versions. If you are using the GUI be sure to check the box for ["allow generation of asynchronous operations" and that "Generate task-based operations" is selected](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S082T.png), if the radio button for tasks [is greyed out](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IYdmT.png) you either need to target a newer version of .NET or use `svcutil` to generate the proxy.

Comment: @SLaks I asked about wasting a thread, and I think I get it now. Two threads are still used, it's just that in the sync request on background thread, that thread is *waiting* for the WCF sync call to finish. In the async WCF call, there is no waiting. Does that sound right? New question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19775997/279516

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that the compiler cannot know that the delegate provided to the `StartNew` method will always be executed before your `foreach` loop is.  You know it, and I know it, but the compiler cannot *prove* it given it's current definite assignability rules.

While there are several "workarounds" to just trick the compiler into letting you do this, the best and most idiomatic solution would be to have the task *return a result* rather than mutating a closed over variable.  That way you're not relying on the task's side effects but rather the result itself.  This makes the code easier to reason about (the task and the code using it can be analyzed separately, rather than having the implementation of each dependent on the other) and ensures proper synchronization of memory shared between different threads (a non-trivial task).

As for the actual code, it has already been provided in [dcastro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19731682/1159478):

```
IEnumerable<PingResponse> pingResponses = 
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        using (var prestoWcf = new PrestoWcf<IPingService>())
        {
            return prestoWcf.Service.GetAllForPingRequest(this.PingRequest);
        }
    });
```

Better still, as per [SLack's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731600/use-of-unassigned-local-variable-when-using-async-await/19731783#comment29316180_19731600) you can use a method that is properly asynchronous, rather than using a synchronous method in a thread pool thread.  Doing so allows you to leverage the operating systems ability to notify you of the completion of a network request without wasting the resources of the thread pool by having it sitting there doing nothing productive.

Comment: Two minor changes I would do: 1. Use `Task.Run()` instead of `StartNew()`, it's shorter and will always execute the work on the thread pool. 2. Use `var` here, I think the full type is not necessary here, but it was required by the compiler in the original code.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `StartNew` overload that allows you to return an object: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321455(v=vs.110).aspx

```
IEnumerable<PingResponse> pingResponses = 
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    using (var prestoWcf = new PrestoWcf<IPingService>())
    {
        return prestoWcf.Service.GetAllForPingRequest(this.PingRequest);
    }
});
```